# Explicit solutions for differential system $x'=y^2,y'=x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could the system
$$ \begin{cases}
x'=y^2 \\
y'=x^2 
\end{cases}
$$
be explicitly solved?
I should determine if for every initial condition the system has a solution defined in all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: it is $$x(t)=0,y(t)=0$$ one solution

Comment: Another solution: $x=y=-\frac{1}{t+C}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eliminate $x$ by differentiating

$$y''=2xx'=2\sqrt{y'}y^2.$$

Then

$$\sqrt{y'}y''=2y^2y',$$
$$\frac23y'^{3/2}=\frac23y^3+K$$
and
$$(y^3+K)^{-2/3}y'=1.$$

Unfortunately, the antiderivative of the LHS is far from simple and cannot be inverted analytically.

In the special case $K=0$,

$$-\frac1y=t+C$$ and $$x=\sqrt{y'}=y.$$

---

In the case $K\ne0$, by a suitable rescaling of the coordinates, the relation can be normalized to

$$(y^3+1)^{-2/3}y'=1,$$

giving

$$\int_{y_0}^y(y^3+1)^{-2/3}dy=F(y)-F(y_0)=t-t_0,$$ and

$$y=F^{-1}(t-t_0+F(y_0)).$$

The functions $F$ and $F^{-1}$ have no adjustable parameter and can be tabulated once for all, for instance by Runge-Kutta integration.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that you answered before me... Since they are more or less the same, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @mickep: your relation $x^3-y^3=C$ is quite interesting.

Comment: It is $x^3-y^3=C$. Yes, but still I feel one is stuck in this case. Except if one is able to invert some hypergeometric function...

Comment: @mickep: yep, I fixed the typo in my comment. At least the trajectory is known.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(y%5E3%2B1)%5E(-2%2F3)+y%27%3D1) knows how to solve it (at least something related)...

Comment: @N74: I know that $F$ has a closed form, but $F^{-1}$ hasn't, and you cannot do without it.

Comment: Well, interpolation of values on values of $F$ to get $F^{-1}$ could be a valid alternative to Runge-Kutta integration.

Comment: @N74: my comment was about Alpha solving it with a closed form. Direct numerical resolution for $F^{-1}$ is better.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks! I wasn't clear about the task of the exercise (I should determine if there could exist a solution in the whole real axis for every initial condition, however your answer is more than enough! Thanks again